# Reduce Lambda error: 'Undefined' object is not callable

Tags: python, lambda, undefined, mako

I'm using `cherrypy` and `mako` with Python to create a website.

In one of my HTML files I have the following Lambda function:

```
${reduce(lambda list, cur : '<li>' + someFunction(cur) + '</li>' + 
                             list, object.listing, '')}
```

Where `object.listing` is a list with strings.

Executing results in the mentioned error: 'Undefined' object is not callable. The error doesn't occur, if I remove `someFunction()`. So I assume it has something to do with `cur` being `None` or `Undefined`, but I don't know how to prevent this.

I'm not even quite sure, how the reduce function works.

The whole stacktrace, as requested:

```
[26/Dec/2012:13:15:22] HTTP 
Request Headers:
  REFERER: http://localhost:8080/list
  HOST: localhost:8080
  CONNECTION: keep-alive
  Remote-Addr: 127.0.0.1
  ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  USER-AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0
  COOKIE: session_id=960e569568ded77610f11c48bec0a806f5a4501b
  ACCEPT-LANGUAGE: en-US,en;q=0.5
  DNT: 1
  ACCEPT-ENCODING: gzip, deflate
[26/Dec/2012:13:15:22] HTTP Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 34, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/Ritalin/Projects/splitpot/controller/Splitpot.py", line 54, in event
    return tmpl.render(object=doSomething())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mako/template.py", line 412, in render
    return runtime._render(self, self.callable_, args, data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 766, in _render
    **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 798, in _render_context
    _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 824, in _exec_template
    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "base_html", line 31, in render_body
  File "someFile_html", line 58, in render_body
  File "someFile_html", line 58, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'Undefined' object is not callable
```

Comment: You should show the entire error with stacktrace to make it easier for us to diagnose.

Comment: Show us your `someFunction`. And what is `cur` in your example?

Answer (score 0):

```
'Undefined' object is not callable
```

Means that you're trying to call something that doesn't exist. Call means to execute a function. Best guess with the information you've provided is that `someFunction` doesn't actually exist within the scope you're trying to use it in.

Looking at your stacktrace and reading that you've defined your function within python rather than mako, I think I understand the problem.

http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html#def describes how to define a function within your templates. I don't know of a way to call back to python files from a mako template - but you can write those functions within mako itself.

Comment: How would I correctly use function in a template? How do I import a Python class?

Comment: @cherrun where is `someFunction` defined, and what does it do? Have you defined it within your mako template, or is it defined in a python file?

Comment: It is defined in a python file. The function returns a specific string, depending on the value given.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is (hence CW), just wanted to point out that a list comprehension might be a better choice here than `reduce`:

```
html = ''.join('<li>' + someFunction(x) + '</li>' for x in listing)
```

Note that your `reduce` code actually reverses a list, if this is intentional, add `reversed` to the above:

```
html = ''.join('<li>' + someFunction(x) + '</li>' for x in reversed(listing))
```

Also, using `list` (a system identifier) as a variable name is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Does `someFunction()` refer to any function put there, or one particular function? If the latter, can we see that code? Does the code still error when someFunction is replaced with e.g. `(lambda x: x+x)(cur)`?